# Linear transformation independence proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to proofs and here is my attempt at the following problem.  Is it correct? Is it wrong? Any feedback?

Suppose T is a linear transformation and that $T(\vec{u_1})$ and $T(\vec{u_2})$ are linearly independent.  Prove that $\vec{u_1}$ and $\vec{u_2}$ must be linearly independent.

My attempt: Proof by contradiction.

Suppose $\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2}$ are linearly dependent.  Then $\vec{u_1}=k\vec{u_2}$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Because of linear independence, $aT(\vec{u_1)} = bT(\vec{u_2}) \implies a=b=0$

Then $aT(k\vec{u_2})=bT(\vec{u_2}) \implies akT(\vec{u_2})=bT(\vec{u_2}) \implies k = \frac{b}{a}$

However, this is impossible because $a=0$ therefore there is no possible value for $k$ and this means that $\vec{u_1}$ and $\vec{u_2}$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: If $u_1,u_2$ are linearly dependent, it is true that either $u_1 = k u_2$ **or** $u_2 = k u_1$, but you need to assume something first. There is no need to introduce the $a,b$, in fact it is a little confusing. Just stating that $T(u_1)-k T(u_2) = 0$ which is a contradiction is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to show directly. Suppose $\alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2 = 0$. Then
$T(\alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2) = \alpha_1 T(u_1) + \alpha_2 T(u_2) = 0$. Since the $T(u_k)$ are linearly independent, you have $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0$.